# IntelliJ Project Tool Window Shows Different Folders Than Before

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, project

Say my current project is called `project_x`. Normally, in the `Project` `ToolWindow` the outermost directory displayed would be the directory `project_x`, alongside things such as `External Libraries`. Kind of the default, as one would expect.

However, `IntelliJ` displayed a message that I cannot exactly remember, but which said something like "an external change has occured". It then asked me whether to rebuild the current project, and I did.

Problem: now, the outermost directory displayed is my `User` folder, i.e.: `Username [project_x]` -> `IdeaProjects` -> `project_x`

I find this annoying, and would like to know how to revert back to the default settings. Help would be appreciated.

What it currently looks like (it contains my entire user-dir):
[image]

What it should look like (ignore the theme): 
[image]

Comment: Is it possible to provide screenshot of you project tree?

Comment: @y.bedrov I have done so

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Well, while it did work for the above project, it did not work for the other one (made matters worse tbh). So this probably is not a solution in general.

Ok, I figured it out.

I noticed that the blue square next to a directory means that it's the source root. (Both my users directory and my actual project directory had such a blue square, the former obviously not wanted...).

So I did some googling on how to remove such a source root. I didn't find the right answer, but got close enough to figure it out on my own (no idea if I caused any damage to my project though):

Go to `File` -> `Project Structure` -> `Modules`

After looking around I noticed that on the left side I had two modules, one of them having my users directory as source root. I deleted that one, which solved my problem.

I'd still appreciate it if somebody could explain to me why this happened, and how to avoid this in the future, because in the time between asking and answering this question, it has happened to me again...